# Moving information from a controller to a view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mongodb

I need to move data read from a database from a controller to a view and display it to a table. I can read from the database a store information to an object successfully, but I'm getting a `@foreach (var item in Model)` error when I run the page. Here is the method that reads the database:

```
public class DatabaseRead
{
    public static async Task MongoReader(string path)
    {
        {
            MongoClient client = new MongoClient();
            var db = client.GetDatabase("POWA");
            var collection = db.GetCollection<files>("Imported");
            var filter = Builders<files>.Filter.Eq("quote_number", path);
            var result = await collection.Find(filter).ToListAsync();
            foreach (var results in result)
                {
                    ContentDisplay read = new ContentDisplay();
                    read.product_name = results.product_name;
                    read.catalog_number = results.catalog_number;
                }
        }
    }
}
```

and here is my view:

```
@model List<ProductionOrderWebApp.Controllers.ContentDisplay>
@{ ViewBag.Title = "Display"; }

<h2>Order Table>
<table board="1", style ="width:auto">
<tr>
    <th>Item Name</th>
    <th>Catalog Number</th>
</tr>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
<tr>
    <th>@Html.Display(item.product_name);</th>
</tr>
}
```

How can I get the table to display all the entries of the object without getting the error?

**EDIT**

Here is the code for my controller. All it does is call two methods, one to read a CSV file and write to mongo, and one that reads from the database and attempts to display the contents.

```
namespace ProductionOrderWebApp.Controllers
pubic class Homecontroller : Controller
 {
    public ActionResult Index
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Display()
    {
        return View();
    }


    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index(HttpPostedFileBase file)

    {
        if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            var fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            var path = System.IO.Path.Combine(("C:\\Dev\\ProductionOrderWebApp\\Uploads"), fileName);
            file.SaveAs(path);
            await CSVRead.CSVReader(path); //calls a method that reads and takes apart a CSV file
            await DatabaseRead.MongoReader(path);

        }
        return View("Display");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: in your loop `var result in results` you're making a new `ContentDisplay` and doing nothing with it. I expect you're not passing anything to the view.

Comment: You should add your controller code here. You clearly do not create the list which you are passing to your view. @ColmPrunty is right. The Model in your view is null.

Comment: Your method needs to initialize a new instance `List<ContentDisplay>`, and then in the loop, add each new `read` object to the list, and then finally return that list so it can be passed to the view.

Comment: @StephenMuecke could you please show me an example?

Comment: Start by adding your controller code to the question.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I have edited the question to include the controller

Comment: Which view is that for (`Index()` or `Display()`)? And why does the POST method for `Index()` return a view for `Display()`? (some of your code is not making sense) And in neither GET method do you return a model to the view (which needs to be `List<ContentDisplay>`) so the model will be `null` and your `foreach` loop will always throw an exception (unless you test for `null`)

Answer (score 0):

Why are you creating a new object of ContentDisplay everytime in the loop, Because of it, you are not passing the required data to the view,

```
            {
                ContentDisplay read = new ContentDisplay();
                read.product_name = results.product_name;
                read.catalog_number = results.catalog_number;
            }
```

Comment: I figured that was the problem! How can I send the information to the view? I know it was to be done before the loop ends but I'm not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

First, `DatabaseRead.MongoReader` needs to return a `Task<List<ContentDisplay>>` instead of nothing. In that method, you need to declare your return list outside the foreach loop and add to it in there and return like

```
var returnList = new List<ContentDisplay>();
foreach (var results in result)
{
    var read = new ContentDisplay();
    read.product_name = results.product_name;
    read.catalog_number = results.catalog_number;
    returnList.add(read);
}

return returnList;
```

Then instead of

```
await DatabaseRead.MongoReader(path);
```

you need to actually catch it to use

```
var model = await DatabaseRead.MongoReader(path);
```

and then pass it along to the view

```
return View("Display", model);
```

**CAVEATS**

I've not done a lot of async await stuff, so there might be something screwy with returning lists.

I'm concerned that `await CSVRead.CSVReader(path);` is probably also doing nothing while you expect it to do something.

**EDIT**

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    List<ContentDisplay> model = new List<ContentDisplay>();
    if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        var fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
        var path = System.IO.Path.Combine(("C:\\Dev\\ProductionOrderWebApp\\Uploads"), fileName);
        file.SaveAs(path);
        await CSVRead.CSVReader(path); //calls a method that reads and takes apart a CSV file
        model = await DatabaseRead.MongoReader(path);

    }
    return View("Display", model);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The only problem I have is that when I try to return returnList I get a "DatabaseRead.MongoReader(string) is an async method that returns a Task" also the var model = await DatabaseRead.Mongoreader(path) is returning from a foreach loop which draws a "Cannot assign void to an implicity-typed variable"

Comment: Did you change `public static async Task MongoReader(string path)` to `public static async Task<List<ContentDisplay>> MongoReader(string path)`?

Comment: Yup, I got it. But I had to do this: `public async Task<ActionResult> Index(HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {       file.SaveAs(path);
                await CSVRead.CSVReader(path);
                var model = await DatabaseRead.MongoReader(path);
                return View("Display", model);
                
            }
            return View("Display");
        }`

Comment: If you pass it in when you return the view it should be fine

Comment: I figured out the errors, thanks. One last thing, how do I bind the data from the list to the view? I appreciate your help!

Comment: I've edited a method into the answer, is your view Index.cshtml or Display.cshtml

Comment: The Index.cshtml is where I can upload the file and it redirects to Display.cshtml where the table exists and where I want to display the list if that's possible.

Comment: If you're passing the correct model to the view, it should be bound, you may need to debug it to see what's happening

Comment: When I run the code it redirects to Display but I only see the empty table that has two headers Item Name and Catalog Number.

Comment: Put a breakpoint after this line `var result = await collection.Find(filter).ToListAsync();`

Does `result` have any contents?

Comment: Yes, `result` does have contents.

Comment: when you hit `return View("Display", model);`, does `model` have contents?

Comment: I ran breakpoints, both model and result were showing a count of 0. I'm really new to C#, this is my first time using it.

Comment: If `result` has no contents then your problem is in `MongoReader`

Comment: Ok I've fixed the code where `result` and `model` are both counting 5, which makes sense since there are 5 mongo documents. However, nothing is being displayed at the Display view.